# Passing information between two alert dialogs

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

ImageView in first alert dialog opens second dialog to change an imageResource of the ImageView  in the first dialog. However I don't know how to make connection between two alert dialogs

Both have different xml layouts, so I assume that in second dialog I should make a reference to the layout of the first dialog

```
private fun editItemDialog() {
    val dialogBuilder1 = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    val inflater = this.layoutInflater
    val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_dialog, null)
    dialogBuilder1.setView(dialogView)

    var editIconButton = dialogView.findViewById<View>(R.id.editIcon) as ImageView

    editIconButton.setOnClickListener{
        showIconDialog()

    }



    dialogBuilder1.setTitle("Edit mode")
    dialogBuilder1.setPositiveButton("Save") { _, _ ->
       //sth
    }
    dialogBuilder1.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _, _ ->
       //sth
    }
    val b = dialogBuilder1.create()
    b.show()
}
```

---

```
private fun showIconDialog() {
    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    val inflater = this.layoutInflater
    val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.icons, null)
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView)

    //examplary two icons to select

    var travelRB = dialogView.findViewById<View>(R.id.travel) as RadioButton

    var travRB = dialogView.findViewById<View>(R.id.travel) as RadioButton


    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Icon dialog")
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Select an icon")
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Save") { _, _ ->
         //here I would like to change an icon of the ImageView, for example:
         editIconButton.setImageResource(R.id.travel)

    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _, _ ->
        //sth
    }
    val b = dialogBuilder.create()
    b.show()


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a callback to the second dialog

```koltin
fun showIconDialog(callback : (Drawable) -> Unit) { 
        //code 
        callback.invoke(someDrawable)
    }
```

And on the first one you just do this:

```koltin
showIconDialog() { someDrawable ->
        //code to change the layout src icon
    }
```

Comment: I have to admit that using callbacks is new to me. What should I put instead of "someDrawable"

Comment: You should add the icon as a Drawable (for ex.) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.iconFile)

Comment: And on the First dialog where i add the comment you add editIconButton.backgroundDrawable(someDrawable)